# how to make query that can generate the equivalent date range and sum the count in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I am using MONGODB in Ruby on Rails language and I have the following table:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("53d23cb06b69720326e80300"), "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T10:14:04.809Z"), "endtime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T10:02:03.411Z"), "visitor_detail_id" : ObjectId("53cf8b686b697275230f0000"), "stayedtime" : 721.398 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("53d23cb06b69720326f20300"), "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:48:04.595Z"), "endtime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:43:04.353Z"), "visitor_detail_id" : ObjectId("53cf8b686b697275230c0000"), "stayedtime" : 300.242 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("53d23cb06b69720326f30300"), "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:48:04.595Z"), "endtime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:43:04.353Z"), "visitor_detail_id" : ObjectId("53cf8b686b697275230c0000"), "stayedtime" : 300.242 }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("53d23cb06b69720326ed0300"), "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:45:04.368Z"), "endtime" : ISODate("2014-07-24T09:33:04.281Z"), "visitor_detail_id" : ObjectId("53cf8b686b697275230c0000"), "stayedtime" : 720.087 }
```

here i will give starttime and endtime , then i need to count sum of stayedtime as weekly wise like(Week 1,Week 2,Week 3,Week 4 etc)

I want to be able to generate like this:

```
   |   period    | stayedtime |
   |  1/7 - 7/5  |  2000  | 
   | 25/6 - 31/7 |  ....  |
   | 18/6 - 24/6 |  ....  |
   | 12/6 - 18/6 |  ....  |
```

Comment: It looks like your `starttime` happens after the `endtime`?

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB aggregation framework has various [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) that can extract information from dates. You can use the aggregation framework from mongoid via the `.collection()` accessor on the class model you are using:

```
result = Model.collection.aggregate([

  # Query to match documents
  { "$match" =>  {
    "starttime" => {
      "$gte" => starttime, "$lte" => endtime
    }
  }},

  # Group by intervals
  { "$group" => {
    "_id" => {
      "year" => { "$year" => "$endtime" },
      "week" => { "$week" => "$endtime" }
    },
    "stayedtime" => { "$sum" => "$stayedtime" }
  }}

]);
```

Or if you prefer to work with timestamp values ( milliseconds since epoch ) in your response you could take this date math approach instead to get the date value at the start of the week:

```
result = Model.collection.aggregate([

  # Query to match documents
  { "$match" =>  {
    "starttime" => {
      "$gte" => starttime, "$lte" => endtime
    }
  }},

  # Group by intervals
  { "$group" => {
    "_id" => {
      "$subtract" => [
        { "$subtract" => [
          { "$subtract" => [ "$endtime", Time.gm(1970,1,1) ] },
          { "$cond" => [
            { "$eq" => [ { "$dayOfWeek" => "$endtime" }, 1 ] },
            0,
            { "$multiply" => [
              1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
              { "$subtract" =>  [ { "$dayOfWeek" => "$endtime" }, 1 ] }
            ]}

          ]}
        ]},
        { "$mod" => [
          { "$subtract" => [
            { "$subtract" => [ "$endtime", Time.gm(1970,1,1) ] },
            { "$cond" => [
              { "$eq" => [ { "$dayOfWeek" => "$endtime" }, 1 ] },
              0,
              { "$multiply" => [
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                { "$subtract": [ { "$dayOfWeek" => "$endtime" }, 1 ] }
              ]}
            ]}
          ]}
        ]}
      ]
    },
    "stayedtime" => { "$sum" => "$stayedtime" }
  }}

])
```

In either case, the "start of the week" is generally considered to be "Sunday", so if you intend to work from a different day as the "start" then you would need to adjust your math.

This moves the "aggregation" to the server where your only other option would be to process query results in your client code. Generally speaking the server is going to do this much faster and avoid transferring all the matching documents from the collection "over the wire" in order to be processed.

Also see the general [aggregation pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in the official MongoDB documentation for a detailed explanation of each operator used.